# Centering 2 horizantol images

Tags: html, css

I want to center 2 images in the middle of  the page horizontally but they keep stacking up vertically

```css
 .img-center{
 display:inline-block;}
 
 .img{
 text-align:center;}
```

```html
   <div class="img-center">
 <div class="img">  <img  src="Friedrich_Nietzsche.jpg"  width="300px" height="200px"/> </div>
 <div class="img">  <img src="ayn-rand.jpg" width="300px" height="200px"/>  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: .img-center{text-align:center;}
 
 .img{display:inline-block;}

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with flexboxes:

```
.img-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This styles will place your `div.img` horizontally in the center of your div.img-center

Comment: I am not sure that flexbox is necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Small change in css. Please try.

```
.img-center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.img {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution below:

```css
.img-center {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.img {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-center">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="Friedrich_Nietzsche.jpg" width="300px" height="200px" />
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="ayn-rand.jpg" width="300px" height="200px" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have something like this?

The main thing that the outer box tells that the content inside is centered.

```css
 .img-center{
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
 }
 
 .img{ 
   display:inline-block;
 }
```

```html
   <div class="img-center">
 <div class="img">  <img  src="Friedrich_Nietzsche.jpg"  width="300px" height="200px"/> </div>
 <div class="img">  <img src="ayn-rand.jpg" width="300px" height="200px"/>  </div>
 </div>
```

The other way can be, if you use margin: auto, but in that case you need to put the images in one div.

```css
.img-center{
       width:100%;
       text-align:center;
     }
     
     .img{ 
       display:block;
        margin: auto;
     }
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<div class="img-center">
 <div class="img">
   <img  src="Friedrich_Nietzsche.jpg"  width="300px" height="200px"/> 
   <img src="ayn-rand.jpg" width="300px" height="200px"/>  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple change to your css which is compatible with wider range of browsers compared to other solutions presented.

```css
.img-center{
   margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
}
.img{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-center">
 <div class="img">  <img  src="Friedrich_Nietzsche.jpg"  width="300px" height="200px"/> </div>
 <div class="img">  <img src="ayn-rand.jpg" width="300px" height="200px"/>  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick position: relative; left: 50%; and transform: translate(-50%);

```css
 .img-center {
 position: relative;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%);
 }
 .img {
 display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
   <div class="img-center">
 <div class="img">  <img  src="Friedrich_Nietzsche.jpg"  width="300px" height="200px"/> </div>
 <div class="img">  <img src="ayn-rand.jpg" width="300px" height="200px"/>  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

text-align: center; is not a good way to do this.

Place a div around your image, e.g.:

```
<div id="centre">
<img src="path">
</div>
```

In your css set the div to the height and width of you image and set the margins to 0, for example:

```
centre{
width: imgwidth;
height: imgheight;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```